# RDIMM vs LRDIMM DL380p G8

Tags: vmware-esxi, memory, hardware, hp-proliant

I need to increase the RAM on a couple of DL380p Gen8 servers (dual Xeon CPU E5-2640).  24 DIMM slots.  The servers run VMWare ESXi 5.5.

I do not intend to use the existing 8 GB RDIMMs, but just install 16 new 16GB RDIMM or LRDIMMs (256 GB total).  The server only supports DDR3 (RDIMM, LRDIMM or UDIMM).

Initially I was intending to use LRDIMMs, but then I came across this article:

https://www.microway.com/hpc-tech-tips/ddr4-rdimm-lrdimm-performance-comparison/

> Many of our HPC customers are looking for high speed and low latency. In that realm, RDIMMs are the hands down winner.

Under LRDIMM:

> When very large quantities of RAM are the goal, then LRDIMMs are the way to go.

If I read the article correctly, RDIMMs might actually result in better server performance than LRDIMMs in our scenario.

**My question is:** *given the server hardware + amount of RAM + the intended use of this server, is LRDIMMs likely to result in noticeably/measurably better server performance (for tasks where RAM speed matters)?*  If not, I might just as well get RDIMMs (less $)

Here are the specific modules:

LRDIMM: 647653-081 (HPE 16GB 2Rx4 PC3L-10600R-9 Kit)

RDIMM:  672612-081 (HPE 16GB 2Rx4 PC3-12800R-11 Kit)

Note: I plan to use the HPE Server Memory Configurator (https://h22195.www2.hpe.com/MemoryTool/Home/SelectServer) to determine what slots to populate, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest 16GB RDIMMS for that platform. For cost, performance and availability reasons.

Comment: Thanks.  FYI, I just found this link, which backs up your answer: https://zhengwu.org/2016/07/05/lrdimm-or-rdimm-on-esxi-hosts/#more-1101 Here is another one (a bit different scenario) https://community.hpe.com/t5/Converged-Data-Center/A-memory-primer-for-new-BL460cGen8-blades-with-Intel-Ivy-Bridge/ba-p/6791414#.V9NeIJgrJaQ

Answer (score 1):

Well, LRDIMMS are almost certainly where you want to go. The reason being that ESXi uses pretty massive pages to address memory, making the slightly reduced latency pretty irrelevant. A big ol' pool of RAM and a good processor cache will make an ESXi box (or pretty much any well-tuned virtualization host) a large repository for the abuse of virtualization technology in a generic and profitable way.

Then again, if you don't care too much about huge capacity or speed, then the slowest, biggest RAM is the easy choice.